# Windows 8 app adding click event to HyperLinkButton doesnot work

Tags: c#, windows, windows-8, windows-8.1

I have some hyperlinkbutton for which I have added the click listener programmatically. But the code written in the event handler does not get called. Am I missing something? Below is the code

```
    private void createTextBlocksForEachLavel(List<Folder> parents)
    {
        foreach(Folder parent in parents){
            addHyperLinkButton(parent.Name);
        }
    }

    private void addHyperLinkButton(String name)
    {
        HyperlinkButton button = new HyperlinkButton();
        button.IsHitTestVisible = false;
        button.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Bottom;
        button.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
        button.FontFamily = new FontFamily("Segoe UI Light");
        button.FontSize = 20;
        button.Content = name;
        if (!name.Equals(">"))
        {
            button.Click += button_Click;
        }
        hierarchy.Children.Add(button);
    }

    void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       // some code which does not get executed!!!!
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove

```
button.IsHitTestVisible = false;
```

or set it to `true`